# C++ copy Constructor and default constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, derived-class

i am learning c++ and have found a output which i dont really understand.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        A(){ cout << "A+" << endl;}
        A(const A&){ cout << "A(A)" << endl;}
        ~A(){cout << "A-" << endl;}
};

class B{
    public:
        B(){ cout << "B+" << endl;}
        B(const B&){cout << "B(B)" << endl;}
        ~B(){cout << "B-" << endl;}
    private:
        A a;
};

class C : public A{
    public:
        C(const B& b) : b1(b) { cout << "C+" << endl;}
        ~C(){ cout << "C-" << endl;}
    private:
        B b1,b2;
};

void test(A a){
    A m(a);
}

int main(){
    B b;
    C c(b);
    test(c);
    return 0;

}
```

the output is

```
A+
B+
A+
A+
B(B)
A+
B+
C+
A(A)
A(A)
A-
A-
C-
B-
A-
B-
A-
A-
B-
A-
```

I mean the first one, B goes to default sees a we got a member from type A and goes to A thats the 
`A+` than goes back to B and print `B+`. Thats it with `B b;` than `C c(b)` it goes to C, see its public A goes to A and print A+ than goes back see we got a Member B b1,b2 goes to B and B have a member A and goes agean to A and print `A+` and than i dont understand why B(B) ? after this B(B)i dont understand anything.. i try it to debugg but it didnt help me very much, maybe someone can explain why this works like this?

Comment: It would be easier, if you match the output with the line (like cout << "(call) B b";) instead of explaining it

Comment: In the `C` constructor initializer list, `b1(b)` is *copy-initialization* of the `b1` member. As such it invokes the `B` copy-constructor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but why it dont print also ```C+``` in the nextline? 
what confuses me is also the ``` C(const B& b)``` it says the copyconstructor wait for a B Object? and ```b1(b)```call the copyconst. from B? so confusing

Comment: might be a bit unrelated, but you can make that output MUCH more easy to understand by simply using a non standard macro that prints the full name of the function (even if it is a template). Substitute all `cout<<...` with `cout<<__PRETTY_FUNTION__<<endl;` and enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood correctly your question you are trying to understand the output

```
A+
A+
B(B)
A+
B+
C+
```

that corresponds to this declaration

```
C c(b);
```

The class C has base class A

```
class C : public A{
```

So the constructor of the class A is called

```
A+
```

then the data member b1 is created

```
C(const B& b) : b1(b) { cout << "C+" << endl;}
```

The class B in turn has data member A

```
class B{
    public:
        B(){ cout << "B+" << endl;}
        B(const B&){cout << "B(B)" << endl;}
        ~B(){cout << "B-" << endl;}
    private:
        A a;
};
```

So when the copy constructor of the class B is called the data member `a` is created

```
A+
B(B)
```

The class C has one more data member of the class B. It is the data member b2.
So these constructors are called

```
A+
B+
```

And at last the body of the constructor C gets control

```
C+
```

Destructors get the control in the reverse order relative to the order of creating objects.

So the destructors output of the object `c` looks the following way

```
C-
B-
A-
B-
A-
A-
```

You can make the program output more clear with minor changes of the program.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        A(){ cout << "A+" << endl;}
        A(const A&){ cout << "A(A)" << endl;}
        ~A(){cout << "A-" << endl;}
};

class B{
    public:
        B() : i( n++ ) { cout << "B+" << ' ' << i << endl;}
        B(const B&) : i( n++ ) {cout << "B(B)" << ' ' << i << endl;}
        ~B(){cout << "B-" << ' ' << i << endl;}
    private:
        size_t i;
        static size_t n;
        A a;
};

size_t B::n;

class C : public A{
    public:
        C(const B& b) : b1(b) { cout << "C+" << endl;}
        ~C(){ cout << "C-" << endl;}
    private:
        B b1,b2;
};

void test(A a){
    A m(a);
}

int main(){
    B b;

    std::cout << '\n';

    C c(b);

    std::cout << '\n';

    test(c);

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output of this updated program is

```
A+
B+ 0

A+
A+
B(B) 1
A+
B+ 2
C+

A(A)
A(A)
A-
A-

C-
B- 2
A-
B- 1
A-
A-
B- 0
A-
```

Comment: ouh man thanks, i sit 2 days on it.. now i understand it. But something just one thing isnt really clear if i do ```test(c);``` why the copyconstructor of a is double? i mean ```void test(A a){
    A m(a);
}``` test is wait for a A object and A m(a) it just once copy ?

Comment: @Jüngealles There are two times called the copy constructor. The first one to create an argument of the type A and the second time inside the function creating a local object.

Comment: mh, i dont really understand. ```void test(A a)``` is waiting for a argument.. its the same like ```void foo(int i)``` right? and after that ```A m=a ```or is it not the same as A m(a)?

Comment: @Jüngealles In this call test(c); there is used the copy constructor to create a temporary object of the type A from the object of the derived class c. Within the function in this declaration A m(a); there is explicitly called the copy constructor the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a closer look at the `C` constructor (slightly reformatted):

```
C(const B& b)
    :
    b1(b)
{
    cout << "C+" << endl;
}
```

First the `A` constructor will be invoked, as it's a base-class for `C`. That will print `A+`.

Then the `b1` member will be copy-constructed, which will print first `A+` because of the `B::a` member, followed by `B(B)` in the `B` copy-constructor body.

Then the `b2` member will be default constructed, which will print `A+` (again because of the `B::a` member) followed by `B+`.

Then the `C` constructor body will run which will print `C+`.

---

The `C` constructor is really equivalent to this (with comments added):

```
C(const B& b)
    : A(),      // Prints A+
      b1(b),    // Prints A+ and B(B)
      b2()      // Prints A+ and B+
{
    cout << "C+" << endl;    // Prints C+
}
```

Hopefully this will make it easier to see what's going on.